# Change Timeout For ServiceStack GetJsonFromUrl?

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to set the timeout for the GetJsonFromUrl helper method?  Or should I just switch to JsonServiceClient if I need something other than the default 30 second timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the `HttpWebRequest` in all [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) using the optional `requestFilter` delegate, e.g:

```
var json = url.GetJsonFromUrl(requestFilter:req => req.Timeout = timeoutMs);
```